Access to user's Google Drive

Is there any way to get access to saving files on the user's Google Drive without interaction with the user (Without using OAuth 2.0)?
Can I use Cloud Function as a redirect URL in OAuth 2.0 to get access & refresh tokens from the returned code by Google?

I need to get the user's permission to save files on his drive. Users interact with the Google Chat app. Being more precise with Dialogflow CX Integration of Google Chat. I've not found any methods in Google Chat API to get user permissions or the user's profile to proceed with saving files on his drive.
NOTE: I do not have any web page or other kind of resource except Dialogflow CX and Cloud Functions.
I write code in Python


Is there any way to get access to saving files on the user's Google Drive without interaction with the user (Without using OAuth 2.0)?

Absolutely not a user must grant your application consent to access their private data.  The only way to do this is to use OAuth 2.

Can I use Cloud Function as a redirect URL in OAuth 2.0 to get access & refresh tokens from the returned code by Google?

The issue with that will be requesting authorization of the user.  For that to happen the user needs to be displayed the consent screen on their browser.  Im not sure that something you can do from a cloud function.

Won't I be able to open the consent screen on the browser anyway?
I think that OAuth 2 is not so clear to me. Correct me if I'm wrong:

User clicks smth and gets redirected to https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth ?scope=<NEEDED_SCOPE>&access_type=offline&redirect_uri=<MY_REDIRECT_URI>&response_type=code&client_id=<MY_CLIENT_ID>
After redirection to this URL it automatically opens the consent screen. Here user confirms giving me those permissions.
After confirmation access, refresh tokes & several other fields are sent to my redirection URL as an object.


Actually, I also have a Google Chat App (Dialoglfow CX bot). A user is already authenticated in Google Chat so my question is: Is there any solution to get access to the user's Google Drive with Google Chat API or anything else?

well normally i have a website where the user can authenticate and i store the refresh token then the chat app can get the stored refresh token.  remember  to verify your application you are going to have to be able to show your ownership of the domain that the redirect uri is directing to.
